# Terraform create GCP API Gateway and cloud function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, devops, terraform-provider-gcp, google-cloud-api-gateway

I have created a terraform script to make cloud function named master-processor and want the cloud function to be trigger with REST API, both Iam able make enable. But when I request rest api throgh postman it shows

```
`<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head>
<body text=#000000 bgcolor=#ffffff>
<h1>Error: Forbidden</h1>
<h2>Your client does not have permission to get URL <code>/master-processor</code> from this server.</h2>
<h2></h2>
</body></html>
`
```

I am using this terraform script to run

```
provider "google" {
  project = "<project-id>"
  region  = "us-central1"
}
resource "google_project_iam_member" "user_permissions" {
  project = "<project-id>"
  role    = "roles/editor"
  member  = "user:<principal/user email>"
}

resource "google_project_iam_member" "service_account_role_assignment" {
  project = "<project-id>"
  role    = "roles/editor"
  member  = "serviceAccount:<project-id>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com"
}

resource "google_storage_bucket" "bucket" {
  name     = "sample-bucket1"
  location = "US"
}

data "archive_file" "function_code" {
  type        = "zip"
  source_dir  = "<path>/master-processor"
  output_path = "/tmp/master-processor.zip"
}
resource "google_storage_bucket_object" "master_processor_function_code" {
  name   = "master-processor.zip"
  bucket = google_storage_bucket.bucket.name
  source = data.archive_file.function_code.output_path
}

resource "google_cloudfunctions_function" "master_processor_cloud_function" {
  name        = "master-processor"
  description = "My function"
  runtime     = "python38"

  
  available_memory_mb = 512
  entry_point         = "master_processor"
  min_instances        = 1
  max_instances       = 1
  trigger_http        = true

  source_archive_bucket = google_storage_bucket.bucket.name


  source_archive_object = google_storage_bucket_object.master_processor_function_code.name

  service_account_email = "<project-id>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com"

  environment_variables = {
  "REGION"                = "us-central1"
  "PROJECT_ID"            = "<project-id>"
}
  ingress_settings = "ALLOW_ALL"

}

resource "google_api_gateway_api" "api_gw" {
  project  = "<project-id>"
  provider = google-beta
  api_id   = "my-test-api"
}

resource "google_api_gateway_api_config" "api_gw" {
  project       = "<project-id>"
  provider      = google-beta
  api           = google_api_gateway_api.api_gw.api_id
  api_config_id = "my-test-config"

  openapi_documents {
    document {
      path     = "spec.yaml"
      contents = filebase64("<path to>/openapi.yaml")
    }
  }
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "google_api_gateway_gateway" "api_gw" {
  region     = "us-central1"
  project    = "<project-id>"
  provider   = google-beta
  api_config = google_api_gateway_api_config.api_gw.id
  gateway_id = "my-test-gateway"
}
```

and the openapi.yaml contains

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  title: dm-service-api
  version: "1.0.0"
schemes:
  - "https"
paths:
  "/execute":
    post:
      operationId: "algoPayload"
      x-google-backend:
        address: "https://us-central1-<project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/master-processor"
        deadline: 500
      responses:
        200:
          description: "Success."
          schema:
            type: string
        400:
          description: "The IATA code is invalid or missing."
```

I have tried to run manually on console it runs and sucessfully restapi is giving response. I am finding that manually api config need service account but in terraform unable to pass that service account details